# Import .ics file to iOS user calendar

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ekevent

I'm trying to add .ics files to the users calendar. I've tried the UIDocumentInteractionController to do this, but this only shows a preview window and not the view to add the events, like it does when you e.g. open a .ics file with the iPhone Mail App.
this is my code:

```
 NSString * filePath =
[[NSBundle mainBundle]
 pathForResource:@"myCal" ofType:@"ics"];

self.documentController =
[UIDocumentInteractionController
 interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]];

self.documentController.delegate = self;

[self.documentController presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
```

What am I doing wrong? Or is there even a way to just add the events of the .ics file to the calendar programmatically (instead of creating many EKEvents)?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [MXLCalendarManager](https://github.com/KiranPanesar/MXLCalendarManager). A set of classes to parse and handle `iCalendar`(`.ICS`) files. The framework can parse through an iCalendar file and extract all `VEVENT` objects into `MXLCalendarEvent` items. Then, by running the checkDate: or checkDay:month:year you can see if the event occurs on a certain day.